# Save excel converted json data to database

Tags: mysql, json, angular, spring, spring-boot

I have an angular application where I am uploading an excel file with data(with headers). In the angular app I am converting the excel file data to JSON. I need to save this data to the database (mySQL). I am using spring boot in the backend to save this data in the db. How can I do this?

Excel file can contain any number of columns, any amount of data i.e it is dynamic. I need to save this data in the db. What will my entity class look like? If someone can provide my any solution for this it would be of great help.
PS: I am new to stackoverflow so I apologize if there are any errors in my question as english is not my first language.
I am able to show the data dynamically in the angular application but not able to save the converted json into the db using spring boot.

Converted JSON data from excel file in angular:
[
{
"0": 1,
"First_Name": "Dulce",
"Last_Name": "Abril",
"Gender": "Female",
"Country": "United States",
"Age": 32,
"Date": "15/10/2017",
"Id": 1562
},
{
"0": 2,
"First_Name": "Mara",
"Last_Name": "Hashimoto",
"Gender": "Female",
"Country": "Great Britain",
"Age": 25,
"Date": "16/08/2016",
"Id": 1582
},
]

Comment: Saving data with dynamic number of columns is inherently at odds with any sql-based database product as in sql you must declare the columns when you create the table. So, you either need to create new table for every excel file with different columns or you need to store the json file in a json field.  In the latter case, I don't think you can use an ORM to map the entities.

Comment: Also, asking for a solution from scratch without sharing any of your attempts, is usually frowned upon here on SO.